# why I have ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-7

I have two project in Eclipse IDE.

1) first, project named X
2) second, project named Y.

Y have a dependance to X project.

**QUIESTION 1)**  there are 2 way to add dependances in eclipse.  Project->properties->buildpath and there are **"PROJECTS"**  tab and **"Librarys"** tab.

**if** I add my project in "PROJECTS" tab. everything **works**!
if I create jar file using maven  **(mvn package)** and add to librarys **(mvn eclipse:eclipse)** I have  that exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/apache/pdfbox...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox ...
```

**Only X project uses org.apache.pdfbox claees. must I add pdfbox dependances to Y project too?**
how can I solve that problem?... the same is when I create jar of Y...

Comment: You have to add X artifact as a dependency in project Y. It's not necesary to add nested dependencies in this case.

Comment: I think you should package X with dependencies.

Comment: Eclipse manages projects in a different way than Maven. If you set the dependencies for your Eclipse project, it's not automatically also set in your Maven POM file.

Comment: @Jesper Furthermore Maven might overwrite the Eclipse dependencies if you rebuild your project config. This would make OPs dependencies disappear.